# Show that if equality takes place in triangle inequality then one of the vectors is either null vector or they are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, triangle-inequality

Given $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^2$, where $x$ and $y$ - complex vectors and given equality
$$\|x+y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$$
show that either $x = 0$ or $ y = \lambda x, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

I tried to square the equality and see what follows but didn't  come up with anything resembling a good result, how would one approach this ?

Comment: Use that $|| x + \lambda x|| = || (1 + \lambda)x||$ and properties of the norm to bring the scalar outside of the expression. Then do the same approach for the right hand side and compare your answers.

Comment: Alternatively, show that equality in Cauchy Schwartz inequality holds for inner product of x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\|x+y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$$

Squaring on both sides :

$$\|x+y\|^ 2= \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + 2\|x\| \|y\|$$

But as $\|x+y\|^ 2=\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2+2Re \langle x,y\rangle$,

We get :

$Re \langle x,y\rangle=\|x\| \|y\|$

Again as $Re \langle x,y\rangle \leq |\langle x,y\rangle|$ and by Cauchy-Schwarz, $|\langle x,y\rangle|\leq \|x\| \|y\|$,

We must have $|\langle x,y\rangle|= \|x\| \|y\|$, which holds iff $x = 0$ or $ y = \lambda x, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Square both sides to get
$$
\langle x,y \rangle = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 \implies\\
\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + 2 \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y \rangle = \|x^2\| + \|y\|^2 + 2 \|x\| \,\|y\| \implies\\
\operatorname{Re}[\langle x,y \rangle] = \|x\|\cdot\|y\|.
$$